# Customers vs. clientele

Tags: nouns

What is the difference of **customers**(plural) to **clientele**?

> The **customers** of Computer XYZ xyz are not happy with the products anymore.

Vs.

> The **clientele** of Computer XYZ are not happy with the products anymore.

Is this a formality matter or better vocabulary skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be synonymous.

If there's a contextual difference, it's likely that [*customers*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customer) is used more in a retail context:

> The restaurant had many *customers*.

Meanwhile, [*clients*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/client) (or *clientele*) is used more in a professional context:

> The doctor isn't seeing any *clients* today.

---

However, if talking about companies, I can think of no way of easily choosing between the two. Typically, a particular company will settle on one or the other word to describe the people they provide services to. In short, one company might choose one word, while another company might choose the other word. The only way of knowing would be to check their public-facing material or ask them.

Comment: Companies might use Clientele to sound exclusive (or posh) as it's based on a french/latin word. (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clientele#English)

Comment: @Smock, hmm this must be it. Thx very much.